Godot Android program crash without logs
I have a Godot project (source, check 'compile_fail' branch) which crashes on startup, but for some reason only on Android; I can run it on PC just fine. video demonstrating this issue
Logcat does not show anything helpful. The app just crashes silently.

seems like this is a Godot bug caused by enabling logging. I've opened an issue for it, time will tell :)

Even if logcat does not display useful information, you can also use the adb command to capture the log, which can help you analyze the problem. You can try the following adb command to capture the log. The log.txt file is in the folder where your current command is executed.
adb shell logcat -b all > log.txt


using ctrl+f with my package name gave a bunch of errors about null pointer dereference. this also shows that the app crashes due to segmentation fault (how? I'm using pure GDScript, engine bug?). paste of stack trace
